# Getting the value of an input field in HTML and using it in a link url

Tags: javascript, html

I have a search button in html and I would like it link to

```
/home/search/search_term
```

where the search term is the value entered into the corresponding input element.

Something like

```
<input id="input_field"> </input>
<button onclick="location.href='home/search/$(input_field).value'">Search</button>
```

would be ideal.

How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: are you using jQuery, if so add a tag of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `</input>`. Change your code to:

```
<input id="input_field" />
<button onclick="location.href='/home/search/' + $('#input_field').val();">Search</button>
```

If you are not using jQuery, change the code to:

```
<input id="input_field" />
<button onclick="location.href='/home/search/' + document.getElementById('input_field').value;">Search</button>
```

Comment: Consider escaping the input value - `location.href='/home/search/' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('input_field').value);`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `input` elements are self-closing. This means you use `<input ... />` rather than `<input>...</input>`.

Once you've changed that, assuming you have the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/) included, you'd need to change:

```
'home/search/$(input_field).value'
```

To:

```
'home/search/' + $('#input_field').val()
```

If you don't have the jQuery library included this will not work, as the above snippet includes jQuery code. Instead you can use this:

```
'home/search/' + document.getElementById('input_field').value
```